# What is WCS? Please explain

Tags: .net, ogc

I want to know from basic to advance about WCS. Actually I got this term from a job consultant and after a bit googling I found that it is Web Coverage Service. Is is correct or it has got some other interpretation?

And how to use this in .NET?

Comment: In what context have you heard about it before?

Answer (score 2):

The consultant might be referring to Websphere Commerce Server. It is a framework provided by IBM for constructing e-commerce sites. WCS is based on J2EE and not .net though it used to be .net in the very beginning.
Websphere Commerce knowledge is a pretty hot niche skill very much in demand in India right now and so it is highly possible the consultant was referring to this

Answer (score 0):

WCS can alo refer to Windows Card Spaces.  It's relationship to .net, is that it was [added to the .net 3.0 BCL](http://www.infoq.com/articles/akif-dotnet-architect).  [For example](http://books.google.com/books?id=_Y0rWd-Q2xkC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=.net%20card%20space%20namespace&source=bl&ots=R8AvQ8UI-j&sig=WDTEcxoJqVPxCFLV8jXMAJeLVBE&hl=en&ei=hWuhTfm2OJTZiALw9biIAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> WCF allows you to specify a CardSpace
>   identity when connecting through a
>   secure HTTP channel, through types in
>   the System.IdentityModel.Claims and
>   System.IdentityModel.Policy
>   namespaces.